# How do I assign multiple legend labels at once?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

I have the following dataset:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [ [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
      [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
      [9, 8, 7, 6, 5] ]
```

Now I plot it with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y)
```

However, I want to label the 3 y-datasets with this command, which raises an error when `.legend()` is called:

```
lineObjects = plt.plot(x, y, label=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
plt.legend()

File "./plot_nmos.py", line 33, in <module>
  plt.legend()
...
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

When I inspect the `lineObjects`:

```
>>> lineObjects[0].get_label()
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> lineObjects[1].get_label()
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> lineObjects[2].get_label()
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

### Question

Is there an elegant way to assign multiple labels by just using the `.plot()` method?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It is not possible to plot those two arrays agains each other directly (with at least version 1.1.1), therefore you must be looping over your y arrays. My advice would be to loop over the labels at the same time:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [ [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [9, 8, 7, 6, 5] ]
labels = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

for y_arr, label in zip(y, labels):
    plt.plot(x, y_arr, label=label)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Edit: @gcalmettes pointed out that as numpy arrays, it is possible to plot all the lines at the same time (by transposing them). See @gcalmettes answer & comments for details.

Answer (score 69):

You can iterate over your line objects list, so labels are individually assigned. An example with the built-in python `iter` function:

```
lineObjects = plt.plot(x, y)
plt.legend(iter(lineObjects), ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))`
```

**Edit:** after updating to matplotlib 1.1.1, it looks like the `plt.plot(x, y)`, with y as a list of lists (as provided by the author of the question), doesn't work anymore. The one step plotting without iteration over the y arrays is still possible thought after passing y as `numpy.array` (assuming (numpy)[http://numpy.scipy.org/] as been previously imported).

In this case, use `plt.plot(x, y)` (if the data in the 2D y array are arranged as columns [axis 1]) or `plt.plot(x, y.transpose())` (if the data in the 2D y array are arranged as rows [axis 0])

**Edit 2:** as pointed by @pelson (see commentary below), the `iter` function is unnecessary and a simple `plt.legend(lineObjects, ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))` works perfectly

Comment: This doesn't work for the user (the x and y's provided cannot be plotted at the same time without an iteration step). Even if the plotting did work, assuming the lineObjects is a list (or tuple etc.), the iter function would be unnecessary.

Comment: @pelson indeed, it looks like it doesn't work with the new matplotlib release. However, if x and y are `numpy arrays`, you can still plot them in one step with `plot(x, y.transpose())`. In this case, the syntax with the iter function is still valid.

Comment: Your right, I didn't know a simple transpose would solve it. (numpy arrays can be transposed with .T by the way i.e. `y.T`). 

However, I still stand by the claim that your iter function is unnecessary here (although obviously it still works).

Comment: @pelson you're right, a simple `legend(lineObjects, ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))` perfectly works. I don't know why I added the `iter` function here ... thanks

Answer (score 41):

I came over the same problem and now I found a solution that is most easy! Hopefully that's not too late for you. No iterator, just assign your result to a structure...

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from numpy.random import *

a = rand(4,4)
a
>>> array([[ 0.33562406,  0.96967617,  0.69730654,  0.46542408],
   [ 0.85707323,  0.37398595,  0.82455736,  0.72127002],
   [ 0.19530943,  0.4376796 ,  0.62653007,  0.77490795],
   [ 0.97362944,  0.42720348,  0.45379479,  0.75714877]])

[b,c,d,e] = plot(a)
legend([b,c,d,e], ["b","c","d","e"], loc=1)
show()
```

Looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 13):

The best current solution is:

```py
lineObjects = plt.plot(x, y)  # y describes 3 lines
plt.legend(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
```

Answer (score 5):

You can give the labels while plotting the curves

```
import pylab as plt

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [ [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [9, 8, 7, 6, 5] ]
labels=['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
colors=['r','g','b']

# loop over data, labels and colors
for i in range(len(y)):
    plt.plot(x,y[i],'o-',color=colors[i],label=labels[i])

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Stylistically, it is probably more pythonic to iterate over the y lists directly, zipping other lists at the same time (see my answer). If you really must, then rather than doing a range(len(...)) it is preferable to use enumerate(...). 

You still got a +1 though :-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. In this case izip, zip or enumerate do make more sense.

Answer (score 4):

## In case of numpy matrix plot assign multiple legends at once for each column

I would like to answer this question based on plotting a matrix that has two columns.

Say you have a 2 column matrix `Ret`

then one may use this code to assign multiple labels at once

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd.DataFrame(Ret).plot()

plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('Return')
plt.legend(['Bond Ret','Equity Ret'], loc=0)
plt.show()
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

This problem comes up for me often when I have a single set of `x` values and multiple `y` values in the columns of an array. I really don't want to plot the data in a loop, and multiple calls to `ax.legend`/`plt.legend` are not really an option, since I want to plot other stuff, usually in an equally annoying format.

Unfortunately, [`plt.setp`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.setp.html) is not helpful here. In newer versions of matplotlib, it just converts your entire list/tuple into a string, and assigns the whole thing as a label to all the lines.

I've therefore made a utility function to wrap calls to `ax.plot`/`plt.plot` in:

```
def set_labels(artists, labels):
    for artist, label in zip(artists, labels):
        artist.set_label(label)
```

You can call it something like

```
x = np.arange(5)
y = np.random.ranint(10, size=(5, 3))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
set_labels(ax.plot(x, y), 'ABC')
```

This way you get to specify all your normal artist parameters to `plot`, without having to see the loop in your code. An alternative is to put the whole call to plot into a utility that just unpacks the labels, but that would require a lot of duplication to figure out how to parse multiple datasets, possibly with different numbers of columns, and spread out across multiple arguments, keyword or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following to show labels for a dataframe without using the dataframe plot:

```py
lines_ = plot(df)
legend(lines_, df.columns) # df.columns is a list of labels
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a DataFrame, you can also iterate over the columns of the data you want to plot:

```
# Plot figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
# Data
data = data
# Plot
for i in data.columns:
    _ = ax.plot(data[i], label=i)
    _ = ax.legend() 
plt.show()
```

Comment: There is no need to call ax.legend() for each individual column. As the label is set during plotting a single call of ax.legend() right before plt.show() is enough.