# how to plot legend for scatter points without reorganising array?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

points with label is usually presented in X, y form

X is a multi-dimensional array, y is label/class that belongs to each point of X

what I want to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
X = np.array(X)

y = np.array([0,0,1,2])


myCmap = np.array(['r', 'g', 'b'])
myLabelMap = np.array(['car', 'bicycle', 'plane'])

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], color=myCmap[y], label=myLabelMap[y])
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

however this will mess up the legend, as you can see in legend section it plot all labels for all points.

Is there a way to solve this without put the X into different arrays?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Ffisegydd sorry but what is mcve?

Comment: That is a link to a webpage, the details of what an MCVE is are there.

Comment: @Ffisegydd got it, MCVE added

Answer (score 0):

First you find out the unique labels, and the points they refer to. You then plot those points with the labels, and the others without labels:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
X = np.array(X)

y = np.array([0,0,1,2])


myCmap = np.array(['r', 'g', 'b'])
myLabelMap = np.array(['car', 'bicycle', 'plane'])

y_unique,id_unique = unique(y,return_index=True)
X_unique = X[id_unique]
X = asarray(X,dtype=float)

for j,yj in enumerate(y_unique):
    plt.scatter(X_unique[j, 0], X_unique[j, 1], color=myCmap[yj], label=myLabelMap[yj])

X[id_unique] = nan
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], color=myCmap[y])

plt.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481644/how-do-i-assign-multiple-labels-at-once-in-matplotlib) question.

Comment: I'm afraid your solution is not correct, a legend should show the set of status/labels/classes rather than all labels of points. for example, I have 1 million points and totally 3 classes, the legend should contain all 3 classes, rather than 1 million items

Comment: Good point, I didn't notice there were 2 red entries in the legend. I have updated the answer, which should now meet your needs. It is a bit trickier though.