# Add all legend labels simultaneously to plot (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

I want to add labels to a `plt.plot` object all at the same time.  `matplotlib` really confuses me since there seems to be a million ways to plot a figure.  Some people do `fig, ax = plt.subplots` while others just do `plt.plot`.  If I search I can find a few more.

Anyways, how can I add all the labels on, with the data, in one line w/o looping? I've been experimenting with `seaborn` but I don't know how to make it do plain line graphs which is why I'm using `matplotlib`.

**Is there some type of method in either `matplotlib` or `seaborn` where you can give it an array of datapoints to plot (in this case 3 samples of 80 points) along with the labels to get this type of plot?**

Giving my code below so you see the DataFrame I'm building the plot from, but the most essential part to the question is after `#____________________________`

not a duplicate of [How do I assign multiple labels at once in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481644/how-do-i-assign-multiple-labels-at-once-in-matplotlib) because the question is directly asking how to set it up in one line w/o a for loop. the "duplicate" suggested is similar to the solution to my answer below.

```
"""Softmax."""

scores = [3.0, 1.0, 0.2]

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

def softmax(x):
    """Compute softmax values for each sets of scores in x."""
    return(np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x),axis=0))


# Plot softmax curvesy

x = np.arange(-2.0, 6.0, 0.1)
scores = np.vstack([x, np.ones_like(x), 0.2 * np.ones_like(x)])
DF_activation = pd.DataFrame(softmax(scores).T,index=x,columns=["x","1.0","0.2"])

#____________________________
#I have to add them like this
[plt.plot(DF_activation.index,DF_activation[c], linewidth=3,label=c) for c in DF_activation.columns]
#But I want to add them like this
#plt.plot(DF_activation.index,DF_activation,label=DF_activation.columns,linewidth=2)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("softmax")
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If you have mpl 1.5 it is more pandas aware and will extract series names for labels and you can do `ax.plot(idx, 'col1', idx, 'col2', data=df)`.  Why do you care if you can do it in one line or not?  If you really want this, just write a helper function `def one_liner_plot(ax, df):` with the forloop in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I assign multiple labels at once in matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481644/how-do-i-assign-multiple-labels-at-once-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean the labels for the legend. You can state directly, in one instruction, both the [labels](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) and the objects they refer to:

```
 legend((plot1, plot2, plot3), ('label1', 'label2', 'label3'))
```

But this mean you need to put your plot into a variable.

```
 plot, = ...
```

Than just use variable to reference the list of labels in the legend function.