# How to add 'one-to-one' legend to each plot line (matplotlib in Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, subplot

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.plot(hpi_data, label = hpi_data.columns.values) #<-- how to add values to each plot?
ax1.plot(benchmark, linewidth=3, label='Benchmark')

plt.legend(loc=2, ncol=2, prop={'size':12}).get_frame().set_alpha(0.1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Please see the legends, it looks kind of messy. Does anyone know how to assign each label to each plot accordingly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I assign multiple labels at once in matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481644/how-do-i-assign-multiple-labels-at-once-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but I got a clear assignment to each plot:

```
f = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(packages, pk_dictionary.get(4), 'o-', label='delta 4')
plt.plot(packages, pk_dictionary.get(18), 'o-', label='delta 18')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title("Probabilities")
plt.xlabel("Package amounts")
plt.ylabel("Probability")
f.show()
```